# Clicking on gmail from panel indicator opens new window instead of restoring

Tags: unity, indicator, thunderbird, gmail

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and I have Gmail installed as a web app. When the app is minimised, and I click on Gmail from the Panel Mail Indicator, it opens a new window instead of restoring the minimised window. I know I can click on the minimised window from the launcher to restore it, but shouldn't the Panel indicator do that? That's how Thunderbird works.

Answer (score 0):

It is a  bug similar to Nautilus. Check  [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647) out.

By the way, its a `Unity Launcher` bug not specific to any app (as in your case GMail).